# How can we monitor SOLR data fetching speed?

Tags: php, solr

I am using SOLR for searching data. Is their any method to identify SOLR data fetching speed?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean on monitoring the speed of Solr fetching the data, the response from Solr includes a QTime attribute that you could use.

[What is QTime a measure of?](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/What-is-QTime-a-measure-of-td495772.html)

> QTime is the elapsed time (in milliseconds) between the arrival of the 
>   request (when the SolrQueryRequest object is created) and the completion of 
>   the request handler. In other words, it will tell you how long it took to 
>   execute your query including things like query parsing, the actual search, 
>   faceting etc.

If that will meet your need, I would recommend reading the following post from the Solr User Group where options for monitoring this value were discussed.

- [Monitor the QTime](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Monitor-the-QTime-td2469551.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like anything else:

```
$start = microtime(true);
$data = $solr->query('*');
echo (microtime(true) - $start) . 'seconds';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also install a server monitoring tool like New Relic which will give you all sorts of stats about Solr.